# excel 2007 conditional formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a rule for conditional format. I have a row in which each cell has a range of 0-4 and hilights properly per the number its at, but I also need a cell to change color when any of the cells in that row are between 1&4, and go back to no highlight when all the cells in that row are 0 or 4.

Comment: Are we talking all integers or are decimals included?  A quick 1 row example would also be useful.

Comment: Ok, so I'm trying to format A4 so that when cells B4-Z4 have a 1,2 or 3 entered in them cell A4 highlights. no decimals.

Comment: also, cells b4-z4 would only have one cell with anything other than a 0 or 4 at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "Use a Formula..." option on the cell you want to format, and type the following:

```
=OR(NOT(ISERROR(HLOOKUP(2,B4:Z4,1,FALSE))),NOT(ISERROR(HLOOKUP(3,B4:Z4,1,FALSE))),NOT(ISERROR(HLOOKUP(3,B4:Z4,1,FALSE))))
```

This should evaluate as TRUE when it equals 1-3, and be unformatted otherwise.

It's made of a couple of basic principles:

HLOOKUP() will search for the number. It returns an error if it can't find one.

NOT(ISERROR()) will evaluate the HLOOKUP result as TRUE when the result is *NOT* an error, i.e. when the number *is* found in the range.

OR() then compiles three searches for the numbers 1-3, and returns TRUE if any one of them is found.

The formula will cause the cell to format when the final result is TRUE.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @user3075129, in the meantime, you can mark this as the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.